# how to recoverable a spider ,have the ability to restart where it left off.using web scraping and python

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

how to  recoverable a spider ,have the ability to restart where it left off.using web scraping and python.I am not able to restart spider.

Comment: Hey, could you include your code?

Comment: i have not implemented code for this,could you suggest something regarding this

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Jobs: pausing and resuming crawls](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html).